# How to add shadow to selectedBackgroundView UITableViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, uiview

I am trying to add a shadow effect to `UITableViewCell.selectedBackgroundView` but this does not show. When I set the background color I can see this is added, so there is something I am doing wrong in setting the shadow. This is my code below `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
        ///Setting selected UIView
        let selectedView = UIView(frame: cell.frame)
        selectedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.35
        selectedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2)
        selectedView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        selectedView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        selectedView.clipsToBounds = false

        cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView
        cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = false
        cell.clipsToBounds = false
```

Comment: Tried putting this in didselectrowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I think the shadow was hidden by the next cell...

Comment: @Happiehappie Tried it now but still no luck

Comment: @Lumialxk How can I test his?

Comment: You can add cell with clear color to test this.

Answer (score 1):

Double check your selection style. Make sure it's .Default and not .None

```
cell.selectionStyle = .Default
```

I tested your code and it worked fine

Also, it's fine to ignore my comment to your opening post, I did this is cellForRowAtIndexPath and it works as expected